# How to get a spicific tag data from .html() returned value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML which i get it from `$('#article').html()` ,
i don't really know how to accomplish this with `split()` function :

```
<sometag1>some data1</sometag1>
<sometag2>some data2</sometag2>
<sometag13>some data3</sometag13>
```

so how i can split it and get the result such like:

```
result=>some data1
```

i tried this:

```
data1=$('#article').html().split('</sometag1>');
data1=$('#article').html().split('</sometag1>')[1].split('</sometag2>');
data1=$('#article').html().split('</sometag1>')[1].split('</sometag2>')[1].split('</sometag3>');
```

but that didn't really work ,and i think that not a very good code either:

so any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

After you changed your question, this is what you want: (demo below)

```
data1 = $('#article').html().split("<sometag1>")[1].split("</sometag1>")[0]
```

---

Do it like this: `$('#article').find('sometag1').text()`

- First you get the parent element: `$('#article')`
- Then you find it's subelement: `find('sometag1')`
- And Finaly you get it's text content: `.text()`

Demo:

```js
var data1 = $('#article').find('sometag1').text()

// What you want after edeting the question:
var data1 = $('#article').html().split("<sometag1>")[1].split("</sometag1>")[0]

console.log(data1)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="article">
  <sometag1>some data1</sometag1>
  <sometag2>some data2</sometag2>
  <sometag13>some data3</sometag13>
</div>
```

Comment: @MohemmadAlBughdadi how funny

Comment: @MohemmadAlBughdadi I added the code you want. But I would not recomment doing it like this, use the direct way not via string

Answer (score 1):

Jquery:

```
data1=$("#article > sometag1");
 data2=$("#article > sometag2");
 data3=$("#article > sometag2"); 
 /*if you want to get html inside tags then
then add .html() to each of lines up */
```

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript Solution

You can achieve that using `getElementsByTagName("tagName")`, e.g :

```
document.getElementsByTagName("sometag1")[0].textContent; //return some data1
```

Or using `querySelector` :

```
document.querySelector('sometag1').innerText; //return some data1
```

Or `querySelectorAll` :

```
document.querySelectorAll('sometag1')[0].firstChild.innerText; //return some data1
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I too tried [something](https://jsfiddle.net/0jfrfhda/) try it.

my code goes like this

```
var data1=$('#article');
console.log(data1);
var i=0;
var a={};
a[i++]=data1.find('sometag1').text();
a[i++]=data1.find('sometag1').text();
//can do it for any other <sometag> as well
console.log(a);
```

result set was something like this

```
Object {0: "some data1", 1: "some data2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working snippet to grub desired data below.

```js
var result = [];
$('#article > *').each(function(){result.push($( this ).text())})
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="article">
  <sometag1>some data1</sometag1>
  <sometag2>some data2</sometag2>
  <sometag13>some data3</sometag13>
</div>
```

Good luck!